# Excel intermittently opens blank excel and CSV files

Tags: microsoft-excel, python, csv

I have a python script that reads info from MongoDB into a file. It can output either Excel or CSV files.

For some reason when I open the files it either opens as a blank document or showing the contents of the file.

I can open an excel or CSV file. See the contents of the file. Close the file. Go back to it a few minutes later, and the file opens up blank. Sometimes, I can go back to the file after that and open it again and I will see what's in the file again. It's not predictable. It's a crap shoot whether or not I can see what's in the file.

This seems like an excel problem! I've never seen this behavior before.

I don't think the problem is the python script, [but here it is](https://pastebin.com/jeBXbzbv) if anyone wants to take a look at what creates the file.

Has anyone else experienced this? What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: This is a longshot idea, but try calling `writer.close()` (line 419 and probably others) before shutting your script down. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) say you should either be explicitly closing it or using a context manager (`with open...`), and the blank files may be a result. Normally this would be a StackOverflow question or answer, but I'm not sure if the script is the problem or if excel is the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for your suggestion! Yeah I had googled it and found that solution too. I thought this was probably an excel problem. But you're right I'm not sure if the problem is with the script or excel. I will give that a shot and try closing the files in the script and see if that helps.